# Function keeps executing else statement in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, function, capitalize

```py
def capitalize(string, *restToLower):
    if (restToLower == True):
        print(string.capitalize())
                    
    else: print(string[0].upper() + string[1:])
```

OR

```py
def capitalize(string, *restToLower):
    if (restToLower == True):
        print(string.capitalize())
                    
    print(string[0].upper() + string[1:])
```

The above mentioned function always running `else` statement.

I created this function to take a string and convert it into `capitalize` format.

**What I want**

if `capitalize('apple')` - "Apple"

and if `capitalize('aPPle')` - "APPle"

and if `capitalize('aPPle', restToLower = True')` or `capitalize('aPPle', True)` - "Apple"

Comment: If `restToLower` is meant to be a boolean, why are you using `**restToLower`?

Comment: In your own words, why do you think `restToLower` should ever be equal to `True`? What happened when you tried displaying the value of `restToLower`? Is it a boolean? Can a dict ever be equal to `True`? In your own words, when you write `def capitalize(string, **restToLower):`, what *exactly* do you think the `**` does?

Comment: I think you need to understand *args **kwargs. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters) might help.

Comment: It seems like your intention is for `restToLower` to be a single parameter with a default value. What happened when you tried putting `python default value` into a search engine? Did you see examples that show how to give a default value for a parameter? Do they look like your code?

Comment: @not_speshal I want it to be an optional argument I add double ** by mistake! it should be single *.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel well it will make it a keyword argument.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel well I want while calling the function if we do not add ```restToLower = True``` it will just convert the first alphabet of string to capital and if there are more capitals it will not conflict with them. Like I mentioned ```capitalize('aPPle')``` = "APPle".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one but always you have to put the boolean True or False.

```
def capitalize(string, restToLower: bool):
    if restToLower == True:
        return string.capitalize()
    else:
        return string[0].upper() + string[1:]


var = capitalize('aPPle', True)
print(var)
```

Comment: You can make it like I want by just adding ```def capitalize(string, restToLower : bool = False):```. By the way thanks man!!!! 

Answer (score -1):

That's not how you provide [default values for arguments](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-arguments-in-python/). You need to do `def capitalize(string, restToLower=False)` if you want it to be `False` by default. The way you've defined it, `restToLower` is a `tuple` containing any number of arguments you enter after the first, so it will *never* be equal to `True`.

As an experiment:

```
def capitalize(string, *restToLower):
    print(restToLower)

capitalize("abcd")              # ()
capitalize("abcd", True)        # (True,)
capitalize("abcd", True, False) # (True, False)
capitalize("abcd", True, 1234)  # (True, 1234)
```